# UISearchBar bookmark icon is not hiding on scroll

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` integrated in my navigation bar with this code:

```
// not needed because it's default
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Also I add a custom bookmark icon like this:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(icon, for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
searchController.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This produces this weird look in iOS 11.4 and 12.1.4

[image]

It seems that the text field doesn't clip the icon and also doesn't apply the fade animation like for the placeholder and the search icon.

Do you guys see some error on my side?
If not, can someone reproduce this? 
Then it is a bug and I will file a radar.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I worked around the issue by doing this:

```
searchController.searchBar.allSubviews.forEach { $0.clipsToBounds = true }
```

Using this extension to get all nested subviews:

```
extension UIView {
    var allSubviews: [UIView] {
        return self.subviews.reduce([UIView]()) { $0 + [$1] + $1.allSubviews }
    }
}
```

But this is a bit hacky so other solutions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do use `clipToBounds` instead of `layoutIfNeeded()`

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(icon, for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
```